# Jquery linkging to html issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to link this Jquery to my html page?
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
can someone help me? Iv been trying but its not working!
I need to know exactly how?
should I include something between my "head" tags? or body or where exactly?

the code is from code pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVZQQX?editors=0010

code:

```
$(".form").find("input, textarea").on("keyup blur focus", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this), label = $this.prev("label");

  if (e.type === "keyup") {
    if ($this.val() === "") {
      label.removeClass("active highlight");
    } else {
      label.addClass("active highlight");
    }
  } else if (e.type === "blur") {
    if ($this.val() === "") {
      label.removeClass("active highlight");
    } else {
      label.removeClass("highlight");
    }
  } else if (e.type === "focus") {
    if ($this.val() === "") {
      label.removeClass("highlight");
    } else if ($this.val() !== "") {
      label.addClass("highlight");
    }
  }
});

$(".tab a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");

  target = $(this).attr("href");

  $(".tab-content > div").not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

It works perfectly in code pen, but when I copy it, it doesn't work!
Thank you

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml

Comment: try learning the [basics](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) first. `<html>**<head>**<title></title><script src="" /><!-- link libs like jQuery -->…</head><body><scrip>/* code calling jQuery */</script></body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery via a `<script>` tag.

JS should be loaded at the end of the page (performance reasons) unless you have a solid reason for including it in the `<head>`, i.e. feature detection, JS placement is not under your control (CMS etc.).

Since you're unsure of how to include JS into a web page I feel it's worth noting that you will **need to** include jQuery **before** your code.

Include JS right before `</body>`:

```
    <!-- the rest of your page -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can include it in the `<head>` if you have to (usually later rather than earlier in the `<head>`):

```
<head>
  <!-- meta tags, title tag, link tags for CSS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If you load your code in the `<head>` you'll probably want to wrap it `$( document ).ready();` so that the code doesn't get executed right away. Why? If you try to interact with a DOM (HTML) right away that hasn't been parsed yet you'll run into problems. `$( document ).ready();` will defer the execution of the code until the DOM is ready.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
  // your code here
} );
```

`$( document ).ready()` is not required if JS is included at the very bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

put this in between the head tags of your html page

```
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```